# Сохранить изображение в мета боксе

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

У меня есть MetaBox в Wordpress теме, который загружает изображение, все работает, изображения загружаются, удаляются, но я никак не могу сделать чтобы они сохранялись.

Как возможно сделать чтобы изображение сохранялось внутри этого бокса, а не исчезало когда я обновляю страницу.
Перерыл все что возможно, так и не понял как это можно сделать.

```
    function custom_page_header_markup(){
    global $post;
    $upload_link = esc_url(get_upload_iframe_src( 'image', $post->ID ));
    $img_id = get_post_meta ($post->ID, '_img_id', true);
    $img_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src ($img_id, 'full');
    $have_img = is_array($img_src);

    ?>
    <!-- Upload button -->
    <a href="<?php echo $upload_link ?>" class="upload-image <?php if ($have_img ) { echo 'hidden'; } ?>">
        <input type="button" class="button button-secondary" value="Select image" id="upload-button">
    </a>
    <!-- Image container -->
    <div class="img-container">
        <?php if ($have_img ) : ?>
            <img src="<?php echo $img_src[0] ?>" alt="" style="max-width: 100%;">
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    <!-- delete button -->
    <a href="#" class="delete-custom-img <?php if (! $have_img ) { echo 'hidden'; } ?>">
        <?php _e('Remove this image') ?>
    </a>
    <input type="hidden" class="page-image-id" name="page-img-id" value="<?php esc_attr( $img_id ); ?>" />
    <?php
    }



function header_image_meta_box(){
add_meta_box('image-meta-box', 'Page Header Image', 
'custom_page_header_markup', 'page','side','high');
}
add_action ('add_meta_boxes', 'header_image_meta_box');
```

Comment: а как вы пытаетесь сохранять-то значение? у вас тут только код, который его выводит

Comment: @alenkins Я добавлял код для сохранения значения, но так как он не работал то я его удалил, в этом то и вся проблема, я никак не могу написать код для сохранения чтобы он работал

Comment: Читайте тут https://wp-kama.ru/function/add_meta_box

Comment: @KAGGDesign я прекрасно понимаю как сохранить содержимое, только никак не могу понять как это сделать с изображением, перечитал уже все что только можно, никак не могу найти ответ, эту статью я тоже перечитал множество раз, ответа так и не нашел

Comment: Покажите ваш код с метабоксами, а этот обрывок из вопроса уберите. В нем смысла ноль.

Comment: @KAGGDesign обновил содержимое